# How to load google font in LitElement

Tags: lit-element, polymer-3.x, google-fonts, lit-html

I am using LitElement and I am trying to load google-font at the element level.

I have tried returning it in an HTML literal in the `connectedCallback` event, but it does not work.
I could not manage to do it in the `get styles()` method.

Where should the `<link...>` statement be placed in the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Font Awesome with Polymer LitElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342356/how-to-use-font-awesome-with-polymer-litelement)

Answer (score 1):

You can import an external style sheet by adding a `<link>` element to your template, For details, see [Import an external stylesheet](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#external-stylesheet).

Here's the demonstrate on **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/question-57489637)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the google font in index.html easily:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

or you could create a common style.js file and include it:

```
const $_documentContainer = document.createElement('template');

$_documentContainer.innerHTML = `<style>
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script');
 html,
 body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
 }
 ...


</style>`;

document.head.appendChild($_documentContainer.content);
var importDoc = window.document;
var style = importDoc.querySelector('style');
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

or:

```
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script">
    `;
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/litelement-passing-data-between-components-in-polymer-3?file=side-menu.js)  ( See the red a tag as I imported `Kaushan+Script` )

Comment: Thank you. I was actually looking for a solution to lazy-load fonts in components and not at the index level. Some fonts may only be required for specific components. I believe both your options load fonts upfront.

Comment: @JoceM Did you find a solution for this? I'm also looking for a way to load the font inside the component and not at the index level...